# How to loop through an array with mixed images and thumbnails?

Tags: php, arrays

I try to dynamically populate an HTML page with 2 images, the first a full image and the second a reduced image, but as I can not do AND with a foreach.

In fact, the code is ok, but I want populate my HTML with twos pics of the same folder; but this code bring back all pictures, it doesn't no the diff between the Full image and the Thumbnail.

The script bring back all picture. My folder contain images with specific titles:

```
Full Image = *.jpeg
Thumbnail = *_Low.jpeg
```

I would like to be able to modify my code to insert the full in the first line and the thumbnail in the second line.

```
<?php

$dir    = './style/images/art/mairie/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$images = array();
array().sort();
$nb = 1;    
foreach($files as $file) {
if(fnmatch('*.jpg',$file)) {
$images[] = $file;
}
}

var_dump($images);

foreach ($images as $image)  {


echo  '<div class="cbp-item">'.'<a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio" href="style/images/art/mairie/'.$image.'">'."\n"
        .'<div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">'.'<img src="style/images/art/mairie/'.$image.'" alt="" /> </div>'."\n"
        .'<div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">'."\n"
          .'<div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">'."\n"
            .'<div class="cbp-l-caption-body">'."\n"
              .'<div class="cbp-l-caption-title"><span class="cbp-plus">'.'</span></div>'."\n"
            .'</div>'."\n"
          .'</div>'."\n"
        .'</div>'."\n"
        .'<!--/.cbp-caption-activeWrap --> '."\n"
        .'</a> </div>'."\n";



}   


?>
```

for the second line I would like to bring back the reduced photo, so to have

```
<div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img 
src="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399_Low.jpg" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

#### $images

Part of my `$images` array would look like this:

```
$images = [
    "0" => "Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg",
    "1" => "Maurine_Tric-7399_Low.jpg",
    "2" => "Maurine_Tric-7407.jpg",
    "3" => "Maurine_Tric-7407_Low.jpg",
    "4" => "Maurine_Tric-7414.jpg",
    "5" => "Maurine_Tric-7414_Low.jpg",
];
```

#### Desired Output

I'm trying to add one of the URLs in my array with large images, and the other with its thumbnail which are being differentiated with `_Low`:

```
<div class="cbp-item"><a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio" href="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg"> <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399_Low.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what the actual HTML looks like please. You also haven't actually given us any information about what your code is NOT doing or is doing incorrectly.

Comment: In fact, the code is ok, but i want populate my HTML with twos pics of the same folder... but this code bring back all pictures, it doesn't no the diff between the Full image and the Thumbnail.
the script bring back all picture....
My folder contain images with specific titles: 
and the ending is either 
Thumbnail = *_Low.jpeg
I would like to be able to modify my code to bring back the two images and to insert it in my grid

Comment: Look into using [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to narrow down the files you are looking for. Based on your comment you have more than enough information to narrow things down and be very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of [fnmatch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php), matching only the thumbail images and marking the part *before* `_Low.jpg` as [Subpattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).
Then you can easily construct the filename of *both* images from that stub:

```php
<?php

$dir = './style/images/art/mairie/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$images = array();
array().sort();   
$matches = NULL;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (preg_match('/^(.+)_Low\.jpg$/', $file, $matches)) {
        $images[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<div class="cbp-item"><a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio" href="' . $dir . $image . '.jpg"> <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="' . $dir . $image . '_Low.jpg" alt="" /></div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/10027904/chris-scheurle i will try

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to just add one URL for our images and one for their thumbs in the `foreach`, we might be able to define a `$html` variable and step by step add to it, then we would finally `echo` that, and our code would look like something similar to:

```
<?php

$html = '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document sans titre</title>
</head>

<body>';

$html .= '<ul>';

$dir = './style/images/art/mairie/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$images = array();
$nb = 1;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (fnmatch('*.jpg', $file)) {
        $images[] = $file;
    }
}


foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        $html .= '<div class="cbp-item">
            <a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio"  href="style/images/art/mairie/' . $image . '">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="style/images/art/mairie/' . $images[$key + 1] . '" alt="" /> </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <div class="cbp-l-caption-title"><span class="cbp-plus"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>';
    }

}

$html .= '</ul></body></html>';

echo $html;
```

---

#### Modifications

What we are modifying here is that we add an `if` to run every other time.

```
if ($key % 2 == 0) {

}
```

We add `$key` var in our `foreach` and finally we have two image links which we replace one of them with `$images[$key+1]`, which one of them is for thumbs:

- `$image`
- `$images[$key+1]`

Comment: Thx Emma, i'm not sure to understand all.... when i scan the folder with $files = scandir($dir); i put the result in an array....but i don't want limit my scan to the thumbnails... i search this result : <div class="cbp-item"><a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio" href="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg">
<div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399_Low.jpg" alt="" /> </div>

Comment: array(190) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "Maurine_Tric-7399_Low.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "Maurine_Tric-7407.jpg"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "Maurine_Tric-7407_Low.jpg"
  [4]=>
  string(21) "Maurine_Tric-7414.jpg"
  [5]=>
  string(25) "Maurine_Tric-7414_Low.jpg"
  ETC

Comment: and then [189]=>
  string(25) "Maurine_Tric-7976_Low.jpg"
}
<div class="cbp-item"><a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio" href="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg">
<div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
<div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
<div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
<div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
<div class="cbp-l-caption-title"><span class="cbp-plus"></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--/.cbp-caption-activeWrap -->

Comment: i search this result : <div class="cbp-item"><a class="cbp-caption fancybox-media" data-rel="portfolio" href="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399.jpg"> <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="style/images/art/mairie/Maurine_Tric-7399_Low.jpg" alt="" /> </div>

Comment: Many Thanks @Emma to help me